# Stray > in the Stack Overflow Labs website

Tags: bug, design, stack-overflow-labs

There is an extra `>` character at the bottom of the page:

[image: Extra > character at the bottom of the Stack Overflow Labs site]

Page URL: https://stackoverflow.co/labs

This should be fixed

Comment: Welcome to Meta Stack Overflow! This site (where your question was migrated to) is for discussing Stack Overflow itself, including bug reports, whereas Stack Overflow (not Meta) is for programming questions. Yep, this is a bug, thanks for reporting it. I wouldn't be too harsh on QA - bugs happen from time to time. A Stack Exchange developer will probably fix this [in six to eight weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/1081494).

Comment: Note that a stray `>` is nearly always something larger going on with the HTML (incorrect escaping in an attribute, incorrect HTML encoding of content, etc), not just someone who accidentally misplaced a `>`

Comment: Given its on a marketing page It’ll probably be 6-8 hours

Comment: @ErikA It looks there's a `&gt;` at the end of the page, so it should hopefully be an easy fix…

Comment: @cocomac That's after you've let your browser interpret the incorrect HTML and translate the `>` to `&gt;`. In the actual source, it's a `>` placed after the `</html>`. Assuming it's not manually written HTML, debugging + fixing might be more complicated than expected.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for flagging this. The extra `>` character at the bottom of the page no longer appears on the bottom of the page. If you're still seeing this issue, please follow up here.